# Angular and Asp.Net Mvc error

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

In Aps.net Mvc views called _LoginPartial.cshtml I've added Angular Controller:

```
    <div class="navbar-right" data-ng-app="PublicApp" data-ng-controller="PublicNotificationsCtrl">
  </div>
```

And that Login partial is rendered on my default layout using:

```
@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
```

And below it I have

```
 @RenderBody()
```

Which renders body which allays has it's Angular controller.

So in html all this looks like:

```
            <div class="navbar-right ng-scope" data-ng-controller="PublicNotificationsCtrl" data-ng-app="PublicApp">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown user-profile-dropdown notifications-dropdown"></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown user-profile-dropdown"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--

        /.nav-collapse 

        -->
    </div>
<div class="">
    <div  data-ng-controller="PublicRoutinesCtrl" data-ng-app="PublicApp">
        <div class="container" data-ng-show="isMainScreen"></div>
        <div class="container special-container" data-ng-hide="isMainScreen"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But my other controllers don't work anymore as if angular is not loaded (for example I see  {{test.Value}} instead of real value)

In console I don't get any errors. Why is this happening ?

**EDIT**

I've put blank div in my main layout page like this:

```
<div data-ng-app="PublicApp" data-ng-controller="PublicNotificationsCtrl">

                </div>
```

But with same result

Comment: Are your other controllers still inside of your root `ng-app` div?

Comment: I don't have root ng-app every time I call controller I do it this way: `<div data-ng-app="PublicApp" data-ng-controller="PublicNotificationsCtrl">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment that you instantiate your `ng-app` with each div, that sounds to be the problem.  You can only have one `ng-app` per page, which is typically the `body` or `html` element in the page.

From the angular docs:

> Only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. To run multiple applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them using angular.bootstrap instead. AngularJS applications cannot be nested within each other.
>   -- http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngApp